# timer driven or endless loop update?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I've been perplexed for a while, whether to run the rendering loop in an endless loop or whether to drive it with a timer (say, a 60 Hz timer). The endless loop seems a good idea, but I am worried it might leech a battery on portable devices faster than the timer approach. In general, consume more energy. I've seen both approaches used in practice, but can't decide on the positive and negative points of them. Can you please help me decide? Perhaps most portable devices are too primitive to support `VSync` updates and hence timer use on them is necessary?

Comment: As someone with a lot of realtime OS experience, the endless loop approach is the best way to get consistent framerate on a normal (e.g. desktop/server) platform; particularly with VSYNC, since missing VBLANK will delay your application by up to 16.5+ ms in the worst-case. As you mentioned in your original question, VSYNC will limit the upper-bound framerate anyway... in fact, adaptive VSYNC on newer GPUs/drivers actually saves power by ***only*** *capping* framerate (rather than re-factoring to the refresh rate to prevent tearing). Is your interest primarily embedded low-power devices?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes, these are my prime interest as GLES is very common nowadays. Can you make your comment an answer? I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Android has capability to do both (Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html), `RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY` or `RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY` flags. Qt and other frameworks also have this. So embedded frameworks do have this capability. However fast you render, note that modern display frameworks (when using their API) will always switch the next frame only at vsync timing, so if you need to draw faster than vsync for some reason, you need to be able to bypass the API (ex, draw direct to the framebuffer).

If the fastest update rate is needed independent of any display synchronisation, go for continuous updates, and this will take more power (not maximum power - you can decide to update selective portions of the screen).

Comment: I know about `android` and GL extension APIs, but I am interested in a more `rule-of-thumb` answer of pros and cons.

Comment: If you are writing an UI application it is always preferred to let the (UI) framework handle this decision, and your code should only update on paint events. Pros of doing this: Power management is transparent to your application, just handle the paint/save events.

Comment: You think too much of UI frameworks, just check the code of android's `GLSurfaceView`, it's a disaster and a huge performance hog. No wonder many games define their own.