# How to implement blinking cursor in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Hi I have a complicated rendering of text and graphics, everything works fine and fast, one missing thing is blinking cursor. I have no idea how to implement it in a way that minimum CPU/GPU power is used?  What approaches could be taken? Any example? Either inverted cursor or color cursor could be used. But color is better. Rectangular is OK, but shaped is better. What I do not understand is how the whole logic of render, glFinish, glClear etc should be organized. Must the whole screen be re-rendered each cursor-blink (450 ms normally). If not, how to achieve only cursor part redraw?Can this be implemented without doing some complicated logic on rendering side? Something like a layer or OpenGL special instruction?

Comment: I think you have many options, from line drawing, to drawing of a texture in a quad. I'd go with the latter, probably from a nine-patch image. You could also use a `.svg` shape. Render it into a texture, then render the texture.

Comment: Drawing is not a problem, problem is how to render (blit, swap surfaces) without redrawing the whole scene, to conserve power.

Comment: Redrawing the whole scene is not a problem anymore. I've made a related question and supposedly, that's the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879498/timer-driven-or-endless-loop-update